# IBM Watson Visual Recognition android sdk failing to load

Tags: android, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

Hi I hope you are doing well,

I'm using the IBM Watson service Visual Recognition with Android, I set the IBM Cloud part correctly, but when I want to work with the service in Android (Android SDK), it doesn't recognize or resolve the dependency.

Photo :
[Android studio didn't recognize IBM Visual Recognition Classes, click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBfJL.png)

Dependency on gradle:

`implementation 'com.ibm.watson:ibm-watson:8.+'`

I want to know if the IBM android SDK isn't working or I missed something somewhere. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the gradle entry above, I think you are referring to Watson developer cloud Java SDK as Watson developer cloud Android SDK’s latest version is 0.5.2 -[Android SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/android-sdk).

If you are using Watson Visual recognition, you can install only Visual recognition piece through gradle by following the steps mentioned [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/tree/master/visual-recognition).

Also, add the gradle entry to `app/build.gradle` as shown [here](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/chatbot-watson-android/tree/master/app)